# How to re-write parts of the Visual Studio Text Editor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, text-editor, vsx

I love visual studio, but the VC++ text editor can be pretty annoying, especially when it comes to determining what should be collapsible. How would I go about writing a Visual Studio extension that overrides parts of the default behavior of the text editor?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the fastest return from trying to find an extension someone else wrote, so start at http://www.visualstudiogallery.com. If nothing there comes close to what you want, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vstudio/vextend.aspx is a dev centre to help you get started extending Visual Studio.